# How to run " $('div').clone().appendTo('.wrapper'); " in LWC?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, jquery, lwc-dom

I want to achieve [this](https://jsfiddle.net/1mx5g452/2/) in LWC.

I want to call the same HTML content (ex- div, p) multiple times in iteration & append them one below other as shown in above link.

I used this

```
$('div').clone().appendTo('.wrapper');
```

in JS, but it won't work...!!!

Can anyone please suggest some alternative. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

In LWC, we usually do not create dynamic nodes this way. It is idiomatic in LWC to use a repeating template (`for:each` and `for:item`) and only change the data that drives the template, rather than clone the template itself. Here, I present what you'd do in LWC.

## [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/PnmEaozZ/2/edit)

---

## css

```
.note {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

---

## html

```
<template>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <template for:each={items} for:item="item">
        <div key={item.key} class="note">
            <div>Content in div</div>
        </div>
    </template>
    </div>
    <lightning-button label="Add note" onclick={addNote}></lightning-button>
</template>
```

---

## js

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    @track items = [
        { key: 0 }
    ];
    addNote() {
        this.items = [...this.items, { key: this.items.length }];
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume,  for keys it should be `this.items = [...this.items, { key: this.items.length}];`, because `{ key: this.items.length+1 }` produces indexes like `0,2,3,4..`. `1` is skipped in this case :)

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi Yeah... this is probably why I shouldn't write answers before my first cup of coffee :p ... Thanks for the comment, I've edited that in to reflect what I meant.

Comment: Thanks so much @sfdcfox ......You have amazing & in-depth knowledge... Please keep helping me :))

Answer (score 5):

You can simply rewrite your jsfiddle jQuery snipper  to LWC next way:

```html
<template>
    <div class="container" lwc:dom="manual"></div>
    <button onclick={onAddNoteButtonClick}>Add note</button>
</template>
```

```css
.note {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {

    renderedCallback() {
        const container = this.template.querySelector('.container');
        container.innerHTML = 
        `<div class="wrapper">
            <div class="note">Content in div</div>
        </div>`;
    }

    onAddNoteButtonClick () {
        const note = this.template.querySelector('.note');
        const wrapper = this.template.querySelector('.wrapper');
        wrapper.appendChild(note.cloneNode(true));
    }
}
```

Main idea here is adding [`lwc:dom="manual"`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_directives) directive to be able to manipulate the DOM within container `div`.

[Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/hYtxP8q4/4/edit)

Comment: Thanks @Oleh Berehovskyi